# Saving date and time in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-datetime

I want to save in a variable the "specific" moment in which an instance of a *class* is created, how can I do that in Python 3? Please, take a look to the following snipped code:

```
class Ants(object):
    """Workers"""
    ID = 1
    def __init__(self):
        import datetime
        self.borningTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.ID = Ants.ID
        Ants.ID += 1
        
    def get_ID(self):
        return "Ant ID:" + str(self.ID).zfill(5)
    
    def get_borningTime(self):
        return self.borningTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %X")
    
my1Ant = Ants()
my2Ant = Ants()

print(my1Ant.get_ID(), my1Ant.get_borningTime())
print(my2Ant.get_ID(), my2Ant.get_borningTime())
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
Ant ID:00001 2018-05-24  17:42:45
Ant ID:00002 2018-05-24  17:42:45
```

And when I run it again:

```
Ant ID:00001 2018-05-24  17:43:05
Ant ID:00002 2018-05-24  17:43:05
```

Which means that *"self.borningTime"* is not recording and keeping its value when I created the instance at the very first time (which is what I want), is getting a new value every time I call it.

How can I do what I want? what I'm missing in my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is recorded each time a **class instance is created**.

The reason why the time is updated each time you run your script is you are creating new instances through these 2 lines:

```
my1Ant = Ants()
my2Ant = Ants()
```

If instead, you subsequently **access attributes only**, without creating new class instances, you will find the times are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your instances are created in the same second.  Put a `time.sleep(1)` between them and you'll see a time change.  You could also use `%X.%f` to print the microseconds of the time, but the resolution of your clock may still create them with the same stamp.

One way to fix this to make sure you have unique times is to wait for the time to "tick":

```
import time

class Ants(object):
    """Workers"""
    ID = 1
    def __init__(self):
        import datetime
        self.borningTime = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Wait for the time to change
        while datetime.datetime.now() == self.borningTime:
            pass

        self.ID = Ants.ID
        Ants.ID += 1

    def get_ID(self):
        return "Ant ID:" + str(self.ID).zfill(5)

    def get_borningTime(self):
        return self.borningTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %X.%f") # Add microseconds.

my1Ant = Ants()
my2Ant = Ants()

print(my1Ant.get_ID(), my1Ant.get_borningTime())
print(my2Ant.get_ID(), my2Ant.get_borningTime())
```

Output:

```
Ant ID:00001 2018-05-24  09:10:41.085253
Ant ID:00002 2018-05-24  09:10:41.100867
```

On my system it took about 15ms to get a new time value.

If you don't need a date/time value, `time.perf_counter()` is much higher precision but isn't related to a particular date and time.  You can only compare the difference between two readings.  On my system it is less than a microsecond per tick, but you can still call it fast enough not to tick:

```
>>> time.perf_counter() - time.perf_counter()
0.0
>>> time.perf_counter() - time.perf_counter()
-3.775817631890277e-07
```